# Luke 4:20 After reading Jesus sat down

Tags: jesus

In Luke 4:20 'Jesus sat down'...

Did He sit down in the chair reserved for the Messiah in the synagogue?

Comment: When scripture is silent, only opinions can be expressed.

Answer (score 0):

In Luke 4:20, the "sitting down" is in the synagogue preacher's chair.  Note the comments of Ellicott:

> **And sat down**.—This conveys to us the idea of falling back to a place of comparative obscurity among the congregation. To the Jew it
> implied just the opposite. The chair near the place from which the
> lesson was read was the pulpit of the Rabbi, and to sit down in that
> chair (as in Matthew 5:1; Matthew 23:2) was an assumption by our Lord,
> apparently for the first time in that synagogue, of the preacher’s
> function. This led to the eager, fixed gaze of wonder which the next
> clause speaks of.

Benson offers similar remarks:

> **And sat down** — The Jewish doctors, to show their reverence for the Scriptures, always stood when they read them, but when they taught the
> people they sat down. See Matthew 23:2. Thus we here find our Lord
> sitting down in the synagogue to preach, after he had read the passage
> in the prophet, which he made the subject of his discourse.

Comment: What does ἀνέκυψεν mean in John 8:7? Did Jesus speak as a Rabbi or a Judge? Or another quality of function?

Comment: @RobertoPezzinFilho - Jesus spoke as a teacher of the eternal truth.  Based on John 3:17, Jesus' function was NOT to sit in judgement.

Comment: I, you and many here know that the authenticity of this pericope lacks unanimity. Jesus did not defend the woman.... Jesus fulfilled Deuteronomy 17:7, the woman's luck was that the witnesses were not suitable... even because the adulterous man did not make himself present in the process requested.

Comment: @RobertoPezzinFilho - I think you may be confusing Luke 4:20 with John 8:1-11.

Comment: If what is posted in this topic is correct, the use of the term ἀνέκυψεν in John 8:7 demonstrates that Jesus was not teaching.

Comment: @RobertoPezzinFilho - that is not true - the accusers address Jesus as "teacher" in John 8:4, while He was sitting somewhere in the temple court (v2).  When they accused her, he leaned over (from the place he was sitting) and wrote in the dust of the temple floor.  The then "straightened up" (v7), ie, sat erect and responded.  Thus, Jesus conducted a classic Rabbinic teaching session by question and answer dialogue.

Comment: The context of ἀνακύπτω occurs in John 8:7, 10 and Job 10:15; Lc. 13:11; 21:28; in what way do you harmonize with the commandment of ἐξαναστήσῃ Lev. 19:32?

Comment: I respect you, not only for the number of positives, but also for the speed of your answers and accuracy.

Comment: @RobertoPezzinFilho - that would be good as a seperate question.  But suffice to say here that "starighten up" is different from "rise" (ie, to stand) as in Lev 19:35.

Comment: Yes, it seems to make sense. I don't blindly trust dictionaries. Unfortunately, I wish I had learned the English language to fulfill your guidance, but in a way, you exercise humility in interacting with me, even if for a short time. It is interesting to listen to diversity, as long as it is not done with the intention of confronting, disrespecting...